# Transactional Inserts and updates in NoSQL

Tags: transaction, nosql

Let's say I'm using Database X which is NoSQL and doesn't support transactions.

```
1. Update A

[error] server goes down

2. Insert B
```

In a scenario, **`A`** is updated and suddenly our server goes down or the second query throws an error. The first query must be rollbacked.

How do we handle that?

Comment: You need to be specific about what "Database X" actually is. "NoSQL" is an umbrella term that covers all sorts of very different database products, each one with its own specific architecture and implementation details.

Comment: If you needed transactionality you wouldn't have chosen the data store that doesn't support it, hence you don't need it, hence you ignore such failures.